# Javascript inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this code:

```
function a() { this.j = "aa"; }
var b = { o:2 };
b.prototype = new a();
alert(b.j); //alert "undefined"
```

Why do I get undefined?

Comment: Because that's not how inheritance works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function a() {this.j="aa";}
function b() {this.o=2;}
b.prototype=new a();
b.prototype.constructor=b;

var c = new b();

alert(c.j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn "b" into a function:

```
function B() {
  this.o = 2;
}
```

Then give it a prototype:

```
B.prototype = new a();
```

Then construct a "b":

```
var b = new B();
```

Then see what your alert reports.